# model.predict() always returns the same value

Tags: python, knn, predict, recommendation-engine

I am creating a recommender system that recommends a book, among those present in the dataset, to the user, based on the data he enters in input.
The problem is that it always returns the same value whatever data I put in.

the code is this:

```
from sklearn.neighbors._classification import KNeighborsClassifier
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


class SuggestAudiobook:
  def __init__(self, book):

    model = KNeighborsClassifier()

    book = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv", delimiter = ";")

    var2 = book.Title

    var1 = book[["audioRuntime_converted", "category_converted",
                 "average_rating_converted", "ratings_count_converted"]]

    var2 = var2.astype('string')
    var1 = var1.astype('int')
        
    model.fit(var1, var2)

    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data = {"audioRuntime_converted": book.audioRuntime_converted, 
                                     "category_converted": book.category_converted,
                                     "average_rating_converted": book.average_rating_converted,
                                     "ratings_count_converted": book.ratings_count_converted})

    predictionDataframe = model.predict(dataframe.iloc[[0]])


    print("Audiobook recommended is --> ", predictionDataframe)
```

I put `dataframe.iloc[[0]]` because it used to give me many values ​​instead of just one.

I am attaching a photo of the dataset     [dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntP7F.png)

Comment: dataframe.iloc[[0]] will give you the first line (index=0) of your dataframe. So if you are feeding your model with the same line all the time - you will get the same prediction

Comment: and so how can i predict only one book as result? because if i remove dataframe.iloc[[0]] i have in output more values

Comment: See below my answer

Answer (score 1):

Prediction for the first 10 rows:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    predictionDataframe = model.predict(dataframe.iloc[i])
    print ('For book: ', dataframe.iloc[i][0], ' I predict:')
    print (predictionDataframe)
```

Comment: applying this code i get this error: ' ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[ 3. 22.  4.  3.]. Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.' . 
however, I did not understand why to do so. I, putting some input data (such as the duration of the audiobook and the category) I want to find only 1 book that I might like given the data entered. But with the code you sent me, I'm basically going to print the forecasts for all the books (?)